pip wheel installation overrides version
I am trying to install a Python package from a wheel:
pip install PyMuPDF==1.24.7 --no-index  --find-links file:///Users/myusername/Downloads/PyMuPDF-1.24.7-cp310-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl

But getting this error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyMuPDFb==1.24.6 (from pymupdf) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyMuPDFb==1.24.6

Why is it looking for different version? How to fix this?
I am on Python 3.10.14 on MacOSX M1
Update:
I tried the version it insisted on and am still getting the same error:
pip install PyMuPDF --no-index  --find-links file:///Users/myusername/Downloads/PyMuPDF-1.24.6-cp310-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl

error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyMuPDFb==1.24.6 (from pymupdf) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyMuPDFb==1.24.6


What's the name of the library you're trying to install?

try pip install /Users/myusername/Downloads/PyMuPDF-1.24.6-cp310-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl

see my answer, its not overriding the version -- its different package ;)

Why --no-index? Is the host offline?

PyMuPDF package depends on PyMuPDFb package.
Because you are explicitly installing with --no-index (eg, package resolving is disabled from network sources) and you are not giving a path for PyMuPDFb package, installation will fail because requirements are not met.
Download that other package too and pass it to pip when installing the main package.
